# Why does the UI not update for async/await function

Tags: javascript

This is my first website created with JavaScript. I'm trying to get items from API and then display them for the user.

My function:

```
getOrderItem = async (itemId: string) => {
    console.log(await api.getItem(itemId))
    return await api.getItem(itemId)
}
```

This is how I'm calling it in my UI:

```
<h4>Quantity: {item.quantity} Name: {this.getOrderItem(item.id).name}</h4>
```

My UI does not update but I can see that the function is working:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong with await/async?

Comment: Are you using react or some other frontend framework that handles state updates and triggers re-renders?

Comment: `getOrderItem` returns a `Promise`

Comment: @katamaster818 Yes. I'm using React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function doesn't return anything until you get your response from the API. And by the time you get your response the UI is rendered already. Since the function doesn't update any state variables your UI doesn't re-render. You should use a state variable to store the response of the API.

```
getOrderItem = async (itemId: string) => {
    let response = await api.getItem(itemId);
    this.setState({items: {...this.state.items, itemId: response}});
}
```

Now, you can use the state variable to re-render

```
<h4>Quantity: {item.quantity} Name: {item.id in this.state.items ? this.state.items[item.id].name ? this.getOrderItem(item.id) }</h4>
```

If you only need the names of the items, you can store response.name instead of response

Comment: Alright it seems like I'm lacking a knowledge about how JavaScript works. The thing is that I wanted to call the function in my UI to get a specific item information. Your solution would give me the same value for all of the items displayed in my website.

Comment: Ohh, so you are rendering multiples items in a single component?

Answer (score 1):

try using the `setState()` hook with the `useEffect()` hook so you can tell React to re-render the DOM elements once your `getOrderItem` fulfills.

You can try setting it up like this:

```js
const [getOrderItem, setOrderItem] = useState({})

getOrderItem = async (itemId: string) => {
    console.log(await api.getItem(itemId))
    return await api.getItem(itemId)
}

useEffect(() => {
    setOrderItem(getOrderItem())
}, [])

return (
    <h4>Quantity: {item.quantity} Name: {getOrderItem.name}</h4>
)
```